# Turning off texture smoothing in Blender Render (Exclusive to Blender Render)

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to make a render of a PSX model and the model's **render** looks horrible. It's really just the textures, and all the answers I look up and people deal with it in Cycles, which I don't understand one bit.

Comment: Change filter size for textures in texture tab. 0.1 value makes them really sharp

Answer (score 2):

Disable 'Interpolation' will make the image texture pixel-sharp.

[image]

Result:

[image]